# protobuf-net + Mono + Linux

Tags: c#, serialization, mono, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net for serializing my data. Everything works fine under Windows, I use Mono to run the sample project under Linux but seems it is not straightforward.

I receive following error:

> Missing method Skip in assembly /home/***/Debug/Di3.dll, type System.Linq.Enumerable
>       Unhandled Exception:
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

The exception is thrown at following line:

```
var instance = new ToSerializeClass();
```

And the class is defined as:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ToSerializeClass
{
    internal ToSerializeClass()
    {// it seems that the protobuf net needs this constructor. 
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    internal int omega { set; get; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    internal List<Lambda> lambda { set; get; }
}
```

I copy the debug/deploy folder to linux, replace the `protobuf-net.dll` and `protobuf-net.xml` with the ones published for `Mono` and call my program using `Mono`.

Am I missing any points here?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure protobuf-net *doesn't use* LINQ. There is a 3.0 build (WCF support), but I've never released a verion that references LINQ (3.5, not including LinqBridge) because I don't need those tools here. Are you sure the problem is where you think it is? I am also confused why you are swapping DLLs after build. That sounds a thoroughly bad idea. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm pretty sure about the above mentioned line of exception. Regarding your last point; I also did a build with proper protobuf-net for Linux but still I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: what exactly did you do for your mono build? Did you use MonoDevelop / Xamarin? Did you use mcs/gmcs from a mono command prompt / shell? Or did you simply build in Visual Studio?

Comment: @MarcGravell, I built in visual studio using the version 2.x of protobuf-net which says supports also Mono.

Comment: yes, but *Visual Studio* doesn't support mono (unless you are using the Xamarin addin). What .net version is your project targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the main problem here is your project setup and build process. Visual Studio, out if the box, does not target mono. If you stick to down-level .net versions (2.0, 3.0, etc) it will *usually just work*, but this gets flakier with higher versions.

The more typical thing to do here is to use a different project/build for targeting mono. This could be MonoDevelop, Xamarin, or `mcs` at the command-line. With these tools, you should be able to correctly compile your project targeting mono and the available framework versions.

In particular, note that protobuf-net does not use LINQ *at all*, and does not reference System.Core - so that load exception has nothing whatsoever to do with protobuf-net. Most likely, the mono runtime simply doesn't recognise the core references you have configured for your test project.

Comment: yes you are right it's working using Xamarin build. I was missing this point; although it seems like all my previous project were running under linux just by some magic ;-) 10x

Comment: @Hamed did your previous projects maybe target down-level .net versions? Or not use LINQ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter which compiler you using csc.exe or mcs.exe. It should work same. If not you should report bug... Btw... Xamarin.Android on Windows is using csc.exe to compile all projects  so csc.exe output should be very compatible with Mono...

Comment: @David what matters is what *libraries* you reference. Not all .net libraries are in mono - and not all libraries are complete. And that is *before* you start asking awkward questions like exactly which mono version. Yes, csc **if instructed to target the right libs** will compile fine. But that isn't what Visual Studio does by default.

Comment: @MarcGravell the projects are targeting .Net4 but are not using LINQ ;-)

Comment: @Hamed the compiler silently removes references that aren't used - if you aren't *using* LINQ, it doesn't matter that you've referenced it - it will never try to load (and won't actually be included in the metadata)